# Use osm2po to extract additional tags

Tags: java, routing, osm2po

We would like to improve our bike routing to also incorporate, for example, the information on the surface of the used streets. I don't quiet get how I should use the Osm2Po plugin in mechanism. I've set up my project in Eclipse and have a working development environment with a custom WayTagResolver (not sure if that is really needed) and a custom PostProcessor that in theory should write the additional information in the SQL file.

Is there a tutorial anywhere that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**osm2po** transforms tags to a simple and flat representation which in most use cases is sufficient. Three attributes exist for this purpose. The `clazz`(byte 1-27) denotes the anchor/main-type. This is mostly set by highway tags. The second one are the `flags` (Integer32). Each parsed tag can indicate its existence in one Bit (flag). These bits must be declared in the `wtr.flagList` before. e.g.:

```
wtr.flagList = car, bike, foot, ..., surfaceA, surfaceB
```

Where *car=1, bike=2, foot=4, ..., surfaceA=32(?), surfaceB=64*

e.g. ***bike|surfaceB=66***

Once declared, you can define simple rules:

```
wtr.allow.tracktype.grade[1|2] = bike|surfaceA
wtr.allow.tracktype.grade[3|4] = bike|surfaceB
wtr.allow.tracktype.grade[5]   = bike|surfaceA|surfaceB
```

where *allow=SetBitFlag* and *deny=RemoveBitFlag*

Theses flags will be written to the pgRouting-Table respectively.
The third attribute is `meta` but it cannot be influenced thru configuration.

So, only if things become more complex, it is necessary to overwrite the API.

Comment: ah okay, thank you @carsten for your quick reply. i will give it a try and report here. on a quick other note, is there a config parameter for the osm2po main class to specify a config file location. it's pretty difficult to edit the version inside the jar file.

Comment: Either modify the osm2po.config (hopefully not that one inside the jar) or overwrite parameters on the commandline. For more complex deviations you can indeed use a parameter to point to another config. `config=path/to/special.config` You can also hold different configs in one by using `wayTogResolver.prefix`